# Customizing iOS Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, titleview

I'm wondering how to accomplish something like this on a UINavigationBar. It is the detail view of a card in the Wallet app.

Based on the documentation, I can't see how to add extra views to the navigation bar to accomplish this sort of design.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't see how to add extra views to the navigation bar to accomplish this sort of design.

You can’t.

In that screen shot, the navigation bar is empty except for the back button chevron. The card image is in the view controller’s view.  That is why it moves up when you scroll up.  If you look carefully as you scroll up, you can even see the card image passing behind the navigation bar.

Comment: There are some cool effects in that window, but they definitely do not involved magically extending the navigation bar down and putting extra stuff into it.